# Get subject Public Key from X509Certificate

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I am working on a model of a private secured network. Anytime an equipment "meets" another equipment in the network, they exchange certificates, that means: A meets B, B generates a certificate of A's public key, and A generates a certificate of B's public key.

My question is: once A receives its certificate from B, I can get B's public key by doing: `cert.getPublickey();`. But how can I check that the certificate is certifying A? I know I can get the name of the Certificate's subject, but I wanted to know if we can get anything better (like the subject's public key for example).

I am working in Java with BouncyCastle's library.

Thank you!

Comment: Define 'B generates a certificate of A's public key'. This is meaningless to me. The way it really works is that A sends B A's certificate along with a digital signature signed by A's private key, which can be verified using A's public key, which is in A's certificate, which proves to B that it *is* A's certificate.

Comment: "A meets B, B generates a certificate of A's public key". How does B know A's public key?

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 1):

> I am working on a model of a private secured network. Anytime an equipment "meets" another equipment in the network, they exchange certificates, that means: A meets B, B generates a certificate of A's public key, and A generates a certificate of B's public key.

No it doesn't. You need to do some reading on PKI. What is supposed to happen is that each party sends its own certificate to the other party, along with a digital signature signed by its own private key. The other party can extract the public key from the certificate and use it to verify the signature, which proves that the first party owned the certificate.

The part about 'B generates a certificate of A's public key' is meaningless.

> My question is: once A receives its certificate from B, I can get B's public key by doing: cert.getPublickey();. But how can I check that the certificate is certifying A?

Via the digital signature: see above.